# are multiple broadcast receivers legal in android?

Tags: android, google-analytics, broadcastreceiver

Is this true?

> Only one BroadcastReceiver class can be specified per application.
>   Should you need to incorporate two or more BroadcastReceivers from
>   different SDKs, you will need to create your own BroadcastReceiver
>   class that will receive all broadcasts and call the appropriate
>   BroadcastReceivers for each type of Broadcast.

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/android.html#google-play-tracking

There is no mention of this in the manifest documentation for `<receiver/>`

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The quoted passage is from the documentation for Google's mobile analytics package. It may be that Google's mobile analytics package cannot support more than one `BroadcastReceiver` for Google's mobile analytics package's broadcasts.

Android itself can most certainly have more than one `BroadcastReceiver` per application.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was thinking/hoping... but that language is not very clear.

Answer (score 6):

The Android platform only delivers the install tracking intent to a single "receiver" for your application. What they mean is, if you are using two install trackers for your application you can not put two receivers containing the same action "com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER". If this is the case, then you can add a meta-data tag like

```
<meta-data android:name="forward.1"  android:value="<other receiver's name>" />
```

to your receiver so both receivers receive the Intent.